# Resistance - same material half diameter

Tags: resistance

Must be an easy question.

The question is:

A wire has R resistance. Another wire same material but half diameter has R' what resistance?

Thank you.

Comment: Must be a homework.  What have you been able to figure out yourself so far?

Comment: Yes it is. Still did not get the notebooks and already got a project. Can find nothing right now on the internet because the formulas I found are in different language than the project was given and I am a bit lost. I mean surely the units are in SI but still have trouble finding the correct answer.

Comment: Everything I found says "Cross-sectional area" and not "diameter".

Comment: And if the diameter is one half, what is the area? Do it for a square, and do it for a circle.

Comment: @MxUser25, so what is the relationship between diameter and cross-section area?

Comment: Yeah found a formula on the net. Is it R = p*l/A.
A is Cross-sectional area. So, d = 2* sqr(a/π)?

Answer (score 1):

Cross sectional area is the area of the end of the wire (assuming a perfectly flat right angle cut). So it's proportional to the square of diameter.

Resistance is inversely proportional to cross sectional area.

So if the diameter is halved
the cross-sectional area is quartered
and the resistance is quadrupled.

Comment: Can you please provide a formula? Do I need to use d=2 sqr(a/π)?

Comment: It would be more normal to write the formula the other way round a=πr²=π(d/2)² and you already found R = pl/a . Substitute the first formula into the second and you have your resistance in terms of diameter, resistivity and length.

Comment: Same material basically implies same resistivity, you didn't explicitly state same length but I would consider it assumed in a question like this.

Comment: Sorry if it's not clear, in my first comment capital R is resistance and lower case r is radius.

Answer (score 0):

For the cross-sectional area of a conductor:

$$ a = \pi r^2, $$

so if the radius doubles the area will quadruple and,  given  constant resistivity, length, and temperature, the resistance of a conductor will vary inversely with its cross-sectional area.

Then, since the diameter of a conductor is twice its radius, we can write

$$ a= \pi \left (\frac D2 \right)^2$$

and for every increase or decrease in the conductor's radius or diameter of a factor of two, the resistance of the conductor will decrease or increase by a factor of four.

It's called an inverse square law relationship, and if I may wax philosophical for a moment, it's one of the things that makes our universe beautiful.

Comment: You're off by a factor of 2.  The problem is in equation 6

Comment: Yup, and needlessly baroque.  I cleaned it up; thanks for the reality check. :)

Comment: So it was baroque, but you fixed it?

Comment: @ScottSeidman: I don't understand what you're getting at.

Comment: Bad pun -  Baroque sounds like broke

Comment: @ScottSeidman:      ARGHHH...  Now I get it! :)

Answer (score 0):

As we know that resistance of a wire is inversely proportional to the square of its diameter. Because the thickness of a wire is usually represented by its diameter.

Thus when the diameter of a wire is doubled (made 2 times), its resistance becomes one-fourth (1/4), and if the diameter of a wire is halved (made 1/2), then its resistance becomes four times (4 times).